# Wordpress/PHP: How to add a class to a child tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a page builder for Wordpress and therefore I can't directly apply a css class to a child tag.

For example,

```
<div class="container">
 <img>
</div>
```

I'd like to add a class to the image tag. How can I achieve this with PHP and potentially adding that PHP code to my functions.php file?

So I'd like to make it look like:

```
<div class="container">
 <img class="custom-class">
</div>
```

I'd greatly appreciate your help!!

Comment: Do you mean the same class to all the `img` tags?

Comment: Why you need to use PHP ? the class  you want to add is located in php var ?
Do you have think to do it with JS ?

Comment: I mean to add any class to the image tag. As I'm using a page builder, I can't directly apply a class to the <img>. That's why I'm trying to achieve this through php

Comment: If i can do this with JS then that work be great as well. Any ideas on how to do that?